# Ensuring Shared Origin when Estimating Camera Pose from Checkerboard Grid in Multiple Photos

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, vision, homography

I have two photos of a stationary scene which includes a checkerboard pattern and a bottle. My goal is to estimate the camera pose relative to a shared origin so that I can perform further processing. My original plan was to estimate camera position using a checkerboard grid. I have concerns about this process though as the checkerboard grid's origin may not be the same in both images. i.e is it possible that due to symmetry in the checkerboard pattern the point chosen as the origin for the checkerboard pattern could vary between photos. If so is there anyway to avoid this while still using a checkerboard grid for pose estimation.

For reference the two images I am using are given below
[image]

[image]

I am deriving the pose of my camera using the code below

```
################### CORNER FINDING CRITERIA ####################
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

################### GENERATE THE OBJECT POINTS #################
squareSZ = 23.876 #Square edge length in mm
dim1 = 9
dim2 = 6
objp = np.zeros((dim2*dim1,3), np.float32) #Generates object points 
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:dim1,0:dim2].T.reshape(-1,2)*squareSZ #Generates a 3d grid from object points

################### LOAD CAMERA EXTRINSICS #####################
camMat = np.array(pickle.load(open('cameraMatrix_GoPro.sav','rb'))) #Loads the camera matrix from the calibration
distCoeffs = np.array(pickle.load(open('distCoeff_GoPro.sav','rb'))) #Loads the distortion coefficients from calibration


################### LOAD CAMERA IMAGES #########################
file1 = 'WaterBottleTooSide/GOPR0250.JPG'
file2 = 'WaterBottleTooSide/GOPR0251.JPG'

# Loads Images
img1 = cv.imread(file1)
img2 = cv.imread(file2)

# Converts to grayscale
img1Gray = cv.cvtColor(img1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2Gray = cv.cvtColor(img2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

################### CALCULATE CAMERA EXTRINSICS #################
ret1, camCorners1 = cv.findChessboardCorners(img1Gray, (dim1,dim2), None) # Find the chess board corners
ret2, camCorners2 = cv.findChessboardCorners(img2Gray, (dim1,dim2), None)

if ret1 == True:
    #Iterates to find the sub-pixel accurate location of corners or radial saddle points
    camPoints1 = np.squeeze(cv.cornerSubPix(img1Gray,camCorners1, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria))
    worldPoints=np.squeeze(np.array(objp)) #Points from my world frame

    retval, rvecs1, tvecs1 = cv.solvePnP(worldPoints,camPoints1,camMat,distCoeffs) #Calculates location using camera and world view points
    rotMat1 = cv.Rodrigues(rvecs1)[0] #Calculates rotation matrix from the rvec
    R_t1 = np.hstack((rotMat1,tvecs1)) #Calculates the 3x4 matrix [R|t]
    P1 = np.matmul(camMat,R_t1) #Calculates the projection matrix
    P1inv = np.linalg.pinv(P1) #Calculate the pseudo-inverse of the projection matrix 4x3 matrix
    C1 = np.matmul(-np.transpose(rotMat1),tvecs1) #Location of camera center for first image
    C1 = np.vstack((C1,1))#Concatenates 1 to create homogenous point

if ret2 == True:
    #Iterates to find the sub-pixel accurate location of corners or radial saddle points
    camPoints2 = np.squeeze(cv.cornerSubPix(img2Gray,camCorners2, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria))
    worldPoints=np.squeeze(np.array(objp)) #Points from my world frame

    retval, rvecs2, tvecs2 = cv.solvePnP(worldPoints,camPoints2,camMat,distCoeffs) #Calculates location using camera and world view points
    rotMat2 = cv.Rodrigues(rvecs2)[0] #Calculates rotation matrix from the rvec
    R_t2 = np.hstack((rotMat2,tvecs2)) #Calculates the 3x4 matrix [R|t]
    P2 = np.matmul(camMat,R_t2) #Calculates the projection matrix
    P2inv = np.linalg.pinv(P2) #Calculate the pseudo-inverse of the projection matrix 4x3 matrix
    C2 = np.matmul(-np.transpose(rotMat2),tvecs2) #Location of camera center for first image
    C2 = np.vstack((C2,1))#Concatenates 1 to create homogenous point
```

Comment: I think this question needs more focus. it's not that you have multiple questions, but that you have one big question mark in your head, and you should have a few more over things you think you understand. cut it down into manageable pieces (of context). this post nobody can digest. additionally, I believe much of this can be answered by throwing books and other education at you, e.g. the size of your checkerboard squares doesn't affect the intrinsics at all (camera matrix, distortion coefficients), only extrinsics (pose camera-board or camera-camera in the stereo/multiview case)

Comment: I second what Christoph is saying. The question is well written and very ambitious, but it doesn’t fit a stack overflow question. If you have a specific error you are running into stack overflow is a great place to ask. This is better on a forum, slack channel, or somewhere else an open dialogue is easily possible. Keep working on it though. Seems like a really interesting problem to solve.

Comment: @Chrisoph Rackwitz I appreciate the feedback I tried editing my question to focus on a  more specific problem. I agree that the breadth of the original post was to great and I am hoping the editedpost will be more focused on a specific problem. I think my post was essentially asking multiple questions even if though they were all related. I also think that it makes sense to stick with a traditional method of using RANSAC for fundamental matrix derivation and still using the grid to account for distortions in the scene

Comment: your checkerboard has no symmetry of concern (90/180 degree in-plane rotational) so there's no ambiguity. in general it may be a good idea to use AR markers instead (e.g. aruco markers/boards).

Comment: rvecs and tvecs: I'd always convert them into 4x4 matrices (using Rodrigues and some slice assignment) because those are so nice to work with. do create utility functions for all that... don't do mysterious squeeze and vstack and whatnot in-line. give those operations names.